# Having trouble putting in the coordinates in global variable [CLgeocoder, swift4]

Tags: swift, mapkit, clgeocoder

I am trying to create an app that will find the sunrise time and I am using this web API that requires both coordinates of the location.

This is my solution for to get the latitude and longitude but then **it does not** let me store the coordinates in the variables.(The coordinates must be float)

Why doesn't it let me put those numbers inside the variables ? or is there a better way of implementing this?

```
   let lattitude: Float = 0.0000
   let longitude: Float = 0.0000


    let address = "Tokyo"
            CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
                if let lat = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate.latitude{
                    print("lattitude : \(lat)")
                    lattitude = lat

                }
                if let lng = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate.longitude{
                    print("longtitude : \(lng)")
                    longtitude = lng
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified that the variables `lattitude` and `longitude` as `let`. These are constants and cannot have their values changed after initialization. Change the `let` to `var`.

Also another problem is `placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate.latitude` and `placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate.longitude` returns type double. You cannot assign a double to a float.

You can either try casting lat/lng to type Float.

`lattitude = Float(lat)`

`longitude = Float(lng)`

Or changing the `lattitude` and `longitude`  variable to type Double.

`var lattitude: Double = 0.0000`

`var longitude: Double = 0.0000`

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue!

Comment: No problem! In the future read and google the errors xcode is giving you, they will tell you what wrong. You can also click on the error and sometimes there will be a 'fix' button that will just fix you problem. Good luck!